# Calcular tiempo de diferencia en Horas y Minutos con PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

Tengo tres campos en las que muestro un tiempo, calculado en base a tres horas.

```
// calculo de diferencia entre las fechas
$date1   = $ticket->date_at;
$date2   = $ticket->visit_date;
$diff    = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));
// calculo de tiempo transcurrido entre las fechas
$years   = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months  = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days    = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
// calculo de horas transcurrido entre las horas
$horallamada   = strtotime($ticket->time_at);
$horavis = strtotime($ticket->visit_hour_in);
$horasal   = strtotime($ticket->visit_hour_out);
$hdiff   = $horallamada   - $horasal;
$hvisdiff = $horallamada   - $horavis;
$hsolution = $horavis - $horasal;

// acá se muestra el tiempo de respuesta

printf("<p>El tiempo de respuesta para este ticket fue de ");  
echo gmdate("H:i", abs($hvisdiff)); printf(" horas.</p>");       
// acá se muestra el tiempo de solución
printf("<p>El tiempo de actividad de la unidad fue de ");
echo gmdate("H:i", abs($hsolution)); printf(" horas.</p>");           
// acá se muestra el tiempo total en cerrar
printf("Este ticket tardó %d años, %d meses, %d días y \n", $years, $months, $days);
echo gmdate("H:i", abs($hdiff)); printf(" horas en cerrarse");
```

`$hvisdiff`, `$hsolution` y `$hdiff` me devuelve lo que se tardó como "02:36", es decir, 02 ***horas*** y 36 ***minutos***.

¿Cómo puedo formatear ésto para mostrarlo así?

Es decir:

> El tiempo de respuesta para este ticket fue de 02 horas con 36 minutos
>
> El tiempo de actividad de la unidad fue de 01 horas con 6 minutos
>
> El ticket tardó x años, x meses, x días y 03 horas con 46 minutos en cerrarse.

Comment: por que no pruebas implementar **Carbon**, que hace la manipulación de fechas muy simple: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: Necesito hacerlo como esta linea: `printf("Este ticket tardó %d años, %d meses, %d días y \n", $years, $months, $days);`, solo que no me resulta hacerlo así.